# Does Neo4j support transactions in standalone mode?

Tags: spring, neo4j

Is it possible to use transactions when Neo4j is used as standalone server? I am using functions from my Spring repositories, and probably each of them is executed as a separate transaction, but I would like to merge them into one. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDN doesn't support remote transactions (which only work with the transactional endpoint and Cypher) yet.

So the option you have to speed your operation up is to move the processing of the SDN entities into the server an expose a domain level REST API to your clients (either with Jersey, or SD-REST).

see: http://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/extending-the-neo4j-server-with-spring-data-neo4j/

Comment: In fact now performance seems to be very bad. In neo4j database logs I see that when I ask for some node there is a GET request not only for node, but also separate one for each relationship. Moreover when I try to persist some node with updated relationships I see that firstly Spring once again retrieve all relationships with separate requests (why?, to compare if there there were any changes?). After that it uses separate PUT to update each not even each relationship but each property in each ralationship! This results with 20s response time for my simple web service, so it is useless.